# Help with wireless internet drivers

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have tried doing all the research and trial and error that I could on my own but with no avail.

So can anyone out there help me? 
I cannot get my **Broadcom b43** wireless adapter to register with Ubuntu. I even tried the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-a-broadcom-wireless-driver), but with no luck. So if someone can help me or at least point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

```
lspci -nn: 
00:00.0 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Host Bridge [10de:02f0] (rev a2)
00:00.1 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 0 [10de:02fa] (rev a2)
00:00.2 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 1 [10de:02fe] (rev a2)
00:00.3 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 5 [10de:02f8] (rev a2)
00:00.4 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 4 [10de:02f9] (rev a2)
00:00.5 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Host Bridge [10de:02ff] (rev a2)
00:00.6 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 3 [10de:027f] (rev a2)
00:00.7 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 2 [10de:027e] (rev a2)
00:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge [10de:02fc] (rev a1)
00:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge [10de:02fd] (rev a1)
00:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 [GeForce Go 6150] [10de:0244] (rev a2)
00:09.0 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Host Bridge [10de:0270] (rev a2)
00:0a.0 ISA bridge [0601]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 LPC Bridge [10de:0260] (rev a3)
00:0a.1 SMBus [0c05]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 SMBus [10de:0264] (rev a3)
00:0a.3 Co-processor [0b40]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 PMU [10de:0271] (rev a3)
00:0b.0 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 USB Controller [10de:026d] (rev a3)
00:0b.1 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 USB Controller [10de:026e] (rev a3)
00:0d.0 IDE interface [0101]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 IDE [10de:0265] (rev f1)
00:0e.0 IDE interface [0101]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Serial ATA Controller [10de:0266] (rev f1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 PCI Bridge [10de:026f] (rev a2)
00:10.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 High Definition Audio [10de:026c] (rev a2)
00:14.0 Bridge [0680]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Ethernet Controller [10de:0269] (rev a3)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration [1022:1100]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map [1022:1101]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller [1022:1102]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control [1022:1103]
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
07:05.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller [1180:0832]
07:05.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter [1180:0822] (rev 19)
07:05.2 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter [1180:0592] (rev 0a)
07:05.3 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller [1180:0852] (rev 05)
```

```
lshw -C network: PCI (sysfs)  

SCSI                      
  *-network        
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=wl latency=0
       resources: irq:19 memory:b3200000-b3203fff

rfkill list: 0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Post the output of `lspci -nn` and `lshw -C network` and `rfkill list`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Broadcom STA driver *wl* is incorrect for your device. Please get a temporary ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot, detach the ethernet and your wireless should be working.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. So simple too. But yeah thanks again, you really helped me out. Now I just realized my headphones work but I have no speaker sound. I just downloaded alsamixer and checked my levels and they were good. Do you have any advice for this problem?

Comment: That's another question which I suggest you post. Will you please accept my answer?

Answer (score -1):

After a clean install of Xubuntu, I plugged in my ethernet cable and did the following:

open terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then after that finishes up, go to settings and see what is in the additional drivers for use. In my case, it had additional drivers for my Broadcom, i checked the radio button, applied it and rebooted. That was it. I didnt see additional drivers until i had a wired connection and ran apt-get update. They then appeared. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is blatantly wrong for this adapter.